# Two JFrames: How to refresh JFrame 1, when JFrame 2 closes?

Tags: java, swing, frame

I have a `JFrame` (1, the main frame) which continues a `JPanel` and `JTable` with data. The user can edit the data. Therefore a new `JFrame` (2) opens and the user can input the new data. If they click "OK" in the 2nd frame, I want the 1st frame to refresh itself.

I have each frame in a different class. Frame 1 knows Frame 2, but not the other way.

I couldn't find a way to make it possible.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Continuing from point 1 of my comment. **This definitely sounds like a good case for a *modal* `JDialog` instead of the second frame, or even more specifically, a `JOptionPane`.**

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (after setting the contents of table):

```
frame1.invalidate();
frame1.repaint();
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame1);
```

Comment: This is a poor approach to this problem, especially noting that the OP says that 'frame 2' does not have a reference to 'frame 1'. See my comment above for (the beginnings of) a better strategy.